# Grails + selenium-rc - submiting an AJAX form

Tags: ajax, grails, selenium, automated-tests

I have a problem with testing an account creation process. Here is the error that I get:

```
Object [object HTMLIFrameElement] has no method 'getCurrentWindow'
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Object [object HTMLIFrameElement] has no method 'getCurrentWindow'
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:97)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:91)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.waitForPageToLoad(DefaultSelenium.java:635)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium$waitForPageToLoad$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at grails.plugins.selenium.SeleniumWrapper.waitForPageToLoad(SeleniumWrapper.groovy)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium$waitForPageToLoad.call(Unknown Source)
    at grails.plugins.selenium.meta.AndWaitDynamicMethod.invoke(AndWaitDynamicMethod.groovy:33)
    at grails.plugins.selenium.SeleniumWrapper.methodMissing(SeleniumWrapper.groovy:125)
    at tokenadmin.SignUpTests.testManualSignUp(SignUpTests.groovy:33)
```

and here is the screenshot:

[image]

and the part of relevant code:

```
    selenium.waitForElementPresent("css=#registerForm");
    selenium.type("name=name", "selenium test 1");
    selenium.type("name=email", emailAddress);
    selenium.type("css=input[tabindex=\"13\"]", "123123");
    selenium.type("name=password1", "123123");
    selenium.type("css=input[tabindex=\"14\"]", "123123");
    selenium.type("name=password2", "123123");
    selenium.submitAndWait("css=#registerForm")
    assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Please confirm your e-mail address"));
```

any ideas what to do?

UPDATE:

I changed everything to localhost:8080 and suddenly it started to work. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the project url to localhost:8080 it started to work

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because of the Javascript security rules. A script 
on localhost can only access a localhost based frame.